# Pgbouncer server parameter

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I installed and configured pgbouncer 1.5.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have a hard time interpreting log messages.

Basically, I have seen many errors:

```
2015-12-10 18:09:16.835 30488 ERROR varcache_apply failed: ERROR: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "localtime"
```

I have googled and some articles told me the root cause is coming from timezone or encoding and date style.

I tried to implement this on `pgbouncer.ini`:

```
db-order= host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port=4326 user=xxxx password=xxxx timezone='Asia/Jakarta' datestyle=ISO client_encoding=UNICODE
```

I then tried to reload the config but still no luck and I am still seeing the same error.

Is the config need to be restarted rather than reloading?

Answer (score 1):

Timezone is a startup variable, you need to restart the pgbouncer service. [pgbouncer.github.io/config.html](http://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html)

*<sub>Wiki answer originally a comment by [3manuek](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/71869/3manuek)</sub>*